# Three.js - Pan camera along X axis on scroll (smoothly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

**The Problem**

I would like to achieve a panning animation like the one found on [this site](http://playdoh-lagaleriedesespeces.com/en/) when you scroll using the mousewheel, i.e. limiting the panning of the camera to the X axis only and making the panning work on scrolling. I would also like this to be smooth/animated like in the linked example.

**Ideas**

1. My first idea is to use the Three.js OrbitControls as they already
   contain a panning feature. I would have thought that I would change
   the controls of the panning from Right Mouse Button to Middle Mouse
   Button, and then limit the plane in which the panning works (X
   Axis).

   I found the following code (from the [source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js) of the
   OrbitControls):

   ```
   controls.mouseButtons = { ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, ZOOM: 
   THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, PAN: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT };
   ```

   And tried changing it to the following inside my script file.

   ```
   controls.mouseButtons = { ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, ZOOM: 
   THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT, PAN: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE };
   ```

   But that did not work.
2. My second idea would be to detect the scroll event using JQuery, and
   then move the actual camera along the X axis when the user scrolls.
   I have not tried this yet as I feel using OrbitControls is the
   correct way to achieve the effect I want, as I know that the example
   site I provided have OrbitControls enabled. I could obviously be
   wrong though.

**What I am looking for**

- Decision on the correct way to achieve the effect I am looking for
- Example code of how to achieve this effect

Thank you!

Comment: FYI `THREE.HorizontalPanning` was added to `OrbitControls` in the dev branch. three.js r.91dev.

Comment: Temporary live link can be found in this PR: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/13453

Comment: @WestLangley Thank you, glad that it's being implemented! Any insight into how the site I linked to may have done it?

Comment: They didn't need all the fancy parts of `Orbit`/`TrackballControls`, so they made their own scroll event handler. On the `mousewheel` event, it dispatches a scroll event to a function which moves the camera. Easy-peasy.

Comment: @TheJim01 So the actual camera is moving itself on `mousewheel` event? i.e. `camera.position.x += 1;`

Comment: Yes, something like that. I'm sure they employ other logic/tricks to make the scene seem continuous, but the real take-away is that they're listening for the generic `mousewheel` event, and handling it themselves.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks for the help, I have almost exactly what I want now, using the javascript `wheel` event to detect direction of scroll and then moving the camera respectively, just need to work on the "smooth" part and then I will write an answer and accept it! Thanks again